# Express route responding with boolean value

Tags: express

I'm creating an API route which I would like to respond with a true or false based on the results of a database search. Here is my route:

```
app.post('/eligibility', function (req, res, next) {
  var current = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  var start = current - (24 * 3600);
  var params = [req.body.guid, start, current];

  client.execute(getEligibility, params, {prepare: true}, function(err, result){
      if(err){
        res.status(404).send({message:err});
      }else{
        if(result.rows.length > 0){
          res.send(true);
        }else{
          res.send(false);
        }

      }
  });
})
```

I'm currently returning `undefined`, what would be the best approach to only returning a boolean value?

Comment: Do you know at what point you're getting to? Can you do `res.send(result.rows)`? Further, you could also just do `res.send(result.rows.length > 0)` instead of the if/else block. I also don't see a `return`, so perhaps: `return res.send()...`?

Comment: yes I can do res.send(result.rows) but sending a boolean value returns undefined, I can console.log it correctly.

Comment: I tried `res.send(true)` and `res.json(true)` with no issue. Something else must be wrong.